# How to throw an error whenever an invalid date object is created?

Tags: javascript, date

I raised strange issue:

```
var d = new Date("2016--01---01");
```

Would create object without any errors. Actually, first question is - why?

But then i need to get string from this object - i am trying to

```
d.toString();     // 'Invalid Date'
d.getTime();      // NaN
d.toJSON();       // null
```

What it is possible ways to get string or check that it is incorrect?

Comment: do you want check whether the provided string is vaild date or not ?

Comment: Do you want to check that the string is valid before creating the `Date()`, or that the `Date()` is invalid afterwards?

Comment: i need to get error on creating or actual wrong date from `Date` object

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check it's a valid number when converted to one:

```
var ok = !isNaN(d);
```

(this conversion is the same than taking `d.getTime()`).

But be warned that a valid date might be not the desired date. You usually use a verified date format. Libraries like moment.js might help you on that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a factory type function which throws an error if the string given produces an invalid date, but returns the date if it's valid

```
var d = createDate("2016--01---01")

createDate = function(str) {    
  var date = new Date(str)
  if(date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.valueOf())) return date
  else throw Error('invalid date')
}
```